# concatenation of strings and variables

Tags: python, string, concatenation

What I need is for it to print "the sum of 1 and 2 is 3". I'm not sure how to add a and b because I either get an error or it says "the sum of a and b is sum".

```
def sumDescription (a,b):
    sum = a + b
    return "the sum of" + a " and" + b + "is" sum
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot concat ints to  a string, use `str.format` and just pass in the parameters a,b and use a+b to get the sum:

```
def sumDescription (a,b): 
    return "the sum of {} and {} is {}".format(a,b, a+b)
```

`sum` is also a builtin function so best to avoid using it as a variable name.

If you were going to concatenate, you would need to cast to `str`:

```
def sumDescription (a,b):
   sm = a + b
   return "the sum of " + str(a) + " and " +  str(b) + " is " + str(sm)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string interpolation, like this. Python will internally convert the numbers to strings.

```
def sumDescription(a,b):
    s = a + b
    d = "the sum of %s and %s is %s" % (a,b,s)
```

Comment: `sumDescription(1.5, 4) -> the sum of 1 and 4 is 5`

Comment: Touche. I guess it'll work to use the string notation because Python will automatically use str() to convert the int/float to a string

Comment: yep, using `%f` would give different output too, str.format just makes life simpler

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to concatenate `string` and `int`.
You must turn that `int` to `string` before hand.

```
def sumDescription (a,b):
    sum = a + b
    return "the sum of " + str(a) + " and " + str(b) + " is " + str(sum)
```